# Scipy intallation error

Tags: python-3.x, scipy

I first got this error:

```
Downloading scipy-0.19.1.tar.gz (14.1MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 14.1MB 36kB/s
Building wheels for collected packages: scipy
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for scipy ... error
  Failed building wheel for scipy
  Running setup.py clean for scipy
  Complete output from command c:\users\appdata\local\programs\python\pytho
n36-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\URO~1\
\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-kk764kiy\\scipy\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize,
'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compi
le(code, __file__, 'exec'))" clean --all:

  `setup.py clean` is not supported, use one of the following instead:

    - `git clean -xdf` (cleans all files)
    - `git clean -Xdf` (cleans all versioned files, doesn't touch
                        files that aren't checked into the git repo)

  Add `--force` to your command to use it anyway if you must (unsupported).


 ----------------------------------------
Failed cleaning build dir for scipy
Failed to build scipy
Installing collected packages: scipy
Running setup.py install for scipy ... error
```

After that it prints bunch of red code("During handling above exception, another excwption occured:", followed by lots of file paths), I didn' paste it here because ther's lots of that and is probably useless for solution of problem.I have python 3 and following error occurs  while trying to instal scipy in cmd.

Then I tried to download from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs.

but it returns error:

`C:\Users\Downloads>C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\
Scripts\pip install scipy-0.19.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl

scipy-0.19.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.`

First two paths is what I wrote(1st is path to where downloaded file is, second to python Scripts file(that's what I shuold do by tutorial))

Can anyone please help me with this problem?

Comment: The scipy version doesn't match your Python version. Looks to me you are trying to install 64bit scipy with 32bit python. Try the 32bit scipy version instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You gotta first install numpy‑1.13.1+mkl‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy. This would remove any previous installed numpy and install a new version of it.

Then you gotta install scipy‑0.19.1‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl like you did.

Note, check your python version, numpy and scipy here are compatible with python 3.6.